# iPad mini and MacBook Pro 2011 Remote control over Keynote?

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro, airplay, keynote

I'm just wondering if there is a solution to run Keynote on my MacBook Pro which is connected to a projector and see in the same time the presenter notes or the presenter screen on my iPad mini?

I have the IR remote control for navigate between the slides but is not so helpfull because the Macbook screen is so far away, near projector and I can't see the notes on its screen even if I make them with very big fonts :)

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions !
Any idea is fine for me

P.S.
The projector does not support AirPlay.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your iPad and your MacBook to the same Network and install [iDisplay](http://www.getidisplay.com/). iDisplay is a software especially designed for your needs. with this software your iPad turns into a external monitor for your MacBook. I use this software since good 2 years and it never failed me!